# Error in downloading data using fastai package in R

Tags: r, fast-ai

I recently chanced upon an article that teaches how to use fastai package in R to train deep learning models [link to article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2023/12/fastai-in-r-how-to-train-deep-learning-models-with-fastai/). I have been able to complete all the initial installation processes as instructed in the article but I got stuck trying to download the data set for the deep learning analysis.When I run the code in the article it throws an error.

This is the code:
#download data

```
URLs_PETS()
```

which throws the error : Error in tabular()$URLs : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Although there is a link to manually download the dataset in case the code doesnt work. I still want to know why I am getting that error.

Comment: Looks like the package author might have made a mistake. You can check by typing the function name without parentheses. Notice that the tutorial said: “ If the function call doesn’t work for you, download and extract the .tgz file from this download link. Either way, you’re ready to move on to the next step.”